# How to add a custom function to product page (backend)

Tags: magento-1.8, product, custom-options

I created a new tab on product information page, it has 6 text box in it (each one with a different link). My goal is to add a simple button in it that show some additional info to the links through a php post. How can i do it?

[image: Image from the tab]

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by additional info its not a very clear request?

Comment: Of course, there is this tab, with 6 links, at the end of the "list" (under the Link 6) put a button, this button must do a request and show the info returned by php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Link 1" and so on are product attributes, you can define a `frontend_input_renderer` for the attributes. This is a class name or block alias and should refer to a class that extends `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract`.

#### Example for a text field with additional content:

```
class Stack_Attribute_Block_Form_Element extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return parent::getHtml() . "Additional Content";
    }
}
```

The additional content can be any HTML, so you can create a button with onclick action that sends some AJAX request.

#### Update your attributes

To update the attributes with the new input renderer, use this in a setup script:

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'link_1', 'frontend_input_renderer', 'stack_attribute/form_element');
```

If you create new attributes, you must use `input_renderer` instead of `frontend_input_renderer`, because `addAttribute()` takes different parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so i created a new helper called helper/Request.php, and its content is: http://pastebin.com/geEpD0dy . I must change anything more on my module?

Comment: This block (not helper!) must be saved in `Block/Form/Element.php`. And don't forget the setup script.

Comment: Ok, i'm trying to create my setup script, but its giving error 500 on server if i enable it. I will fix it and if i have any other doubts i post here again, thanks.

Comment: After i fixed the setup script (i forgot to add Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Model_Resource_Setup to config.xml) when i try to open the product info page it returns this errors: http://pastebin.com/zf82mywG maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: this comes from some Amasty module and I have no idea what data it receives, sorry

Comment: Solved! thanks @fschmengler . Now i'll add the functions. The only problem is that it writes "Additional Content" for every link.

Comment: yeah of course, that was an example. Replace it with your button ;)

Comment: Thanks, its working fine now. How can i import a js to the product info page?